# Build a iptv server using ubuntu and a satelite dish

Tags: tv, mediaserver, video-streaming

My mom father, systers and brothers (huge family) all of them had satelite dishes untill i introduced Android tv box to them. I went to some sites that offers persian channels online i borrowes the links and played them on Kodi. That worked fine untill my brother found out that almost 30 channels just goes offline for halv a day and then they stream again.
This is not illegal since i followed the lawlines they had on website. Instead of seeing the channels on the website I see them in kodi for private use.
Now after complaints I started to think if its possible for me to set up one satelite dish, take those persian channels and stream them to my family's android boxen.
I herd about tvheaded but my problem begins at the begining.

1. I need a satelite dish and reciever
2. I need a server. I use ubuntu.
3. I need some link between these two
4. I need some sofware to maintain the streaming

   5. I need to make it as simple as possible. I want the streaming to go to those android boxen. No one else should use it (i dont wamt to get in trouble )

My problem is 3 4 5. I would appritiate if someone could help me with that.

Comment: For every channel you want to stream, you will need at least one satellite tuner.  So 30x channels = 30x tuners.  Each channel will need to be encoded into a stream-able format such as MPEG2-TS (commonly used for live TV streams).  A fast quad core CPU computer/server should be able to cope with 2-5 streams at a time, so you will need a minimum of 6x servers.  This is a huge undertaking by any standard.  You may be able to substitute the Servers for Raspberry Pi3's but this is still a lot of work.

Comment: So many satelites? So a company that offers 1000 channels has 1000 satelite?

Comment: No, most re-stream from other sources to supplement their catalogue, or pay for IPTV connections.  1x satellite, but lots of tuners.

Comment: So its not way one can get all of the channels at the same time?

Comment: Not using the method you're asking.  The only true way to get all the channels you want with a steady connection, and without lots of servers/tuners, is to pay for an IPTV connection from a reputable supplier.